# Identify duplicate records and assign random ids

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

in a super trouble with some unix stuffs..Any guidance here will be much appreciated.

I want to identify the duplicate records based on their **id** from the below file and assign a unique random number to it in a separate col and sum their **value** field.
my input file:

```
name,location,id,state,website,status,color,field1,value,field3,field4,field5
joe,US,23A,CA,g,oog,le,10,blue,0,10,0,0,0
jack,UK,89A,LN,yah,oo,11,red,0,20,0,0,0
joe,US,23A,CA,g,mail,10,blue,0,120,0,0,0
rose,EU,AV45,UN,new,mail,45,black,0,110,0,0,0
Karl,US,2345,NY,microsoft,99,green,0,34,0,0,0
jonas,IN,AW3455,ND,facebook,37,brown,0,48,0,0,0
Karl,US,2345,NY,microsoft,99,purple,0,87,0,0,0
alin,IN,3T45,CA,re,edit,78,white,0,22,0,0,0
alin,IN,3T45,CA,ora,cle,11,orange,0,35,0,0,0
```

I expect my output file to be:

```
RandonUniqID,ID,Value
2202,23A,130
3029,89A,20
3066,AV45,110
5077,2345,121
1055,AW3455,48
3099,3T45,57
```

Here i wanted to generate unique random id for the rec and those records that are repeating , i want to get their values field summed up in a separate field. the trickiest part here is my 5th col that is **website** is very dynamic.the values in that field will have commas delimiter placed anywhere. So this is getting me in trouble.

Comment: To get the data from the `value` column without having to worry about embedded commas in `website`, use `$(NF - 3) `

Comment: got it. but i'm not sure how to generate a random number for my records and add the values for that. I tried couple of awk stuffs but the varying commas in the value field is getting it all skewed

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49999568/edit) your question to show what you've tried.  What do you mean by varying commas in the value field? Isn't the value field a decimal number?

Comment: no sir. not in the value field. I'm referring to the website field. sorry for the confusion

Comment: You haven't added your code yet. You will get WAY more helpful answers if you include your work so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -F ',' '
   NR>1{
      if( ! ( $3 in UID ) ) {

         # select a uniq random id 
         while( (Rnd=int(1000000*rand())) in UID) i++

         UID[$3]=Rnd
         }
      # workaround for 9th col where there are "," inside field
      S[$3]+=$(NF - 3)
      }
    END {
       print "RandonUniqID,ID,Value"
       for( uid in UID ) printf( "%s,%s,%s\n", UID[uid], uid, S[uid])
       }
    ' YourFile
```

I assume there is lot less id than 1000000

Comment: thanks for the insight. one question. how am i supposed to execute this? should this be executed like a script or in a command format

Comment: should the above program be executed like a command or a  be used as  a script. i'm getting many syntax errors when i tried to run this as cmd

Comment: it's a gawk command (tested here under linux rhel bash). i use the file 'YourFile` as input. Which error do you have ?

Comment: awk:NR>1{if(!($3 in UID)) {while((Rnd=int(1000000*rand())) in UID) i++ UID[$3]=Rnd} S[$3]+=$(NF - 3)}END {print"RandonUniqID,ID,Value"for(uid inUID) printf( "%s,%s,%s\n", UID[uid], uid, S[uid])}testfile
awk:   ^ syntax error
awk:  NR>1{if(!($3 in UID)) {while((Rnd=int(1000000*rand())) in UID) i++ UID[$3]=Rnd} S[$3]+=$(NF - 3)} END {print "RandonUniqID,ID,Value"for(uid inUID) printf( "%s,%s,%s\n", UID[uid], uid, S[uid])}testfile
awk:                                                                                                                        ^ syntax error

Comment: i think i screwed it up.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
awk '# Set the input and output field delimiter and print the headers
     BEGIN{FS=OFS=",";print "RandomID,ID,Value"}
     # iteratively calculate the s(um) per id ($3) on each row
     NR>1{s[$3]+=$(NF-3)}
     # Print the results, indexed by an integer r
     END{for(i in s){print r++,i,s[i]}}' input_file
```

`NF` is the number of fields, `$(NF-3)` is the 4th last field.

This will generate sequential ids like this:

```
RandomID,ID,Value
0,3T45,57
1,2345,121
2,23A,130
3,AV45,110
4,AW3455,48
5,89A,20
```

If you need the ids being 4 chars wide you can use `printf`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";print "RandomID,ID,Value"}
     NR>1{s[$3]+=$(NF-3)}
     END{for(i in s){printf "%04d,%s,%d\n",r++,i,s[i]}}' input_file
```

Output:

```
RandomID,ID,Value
0000,3T45,57
0001,2345,121
0002,23A,130
0003,AV45,110
0004,AW3455,48
0005,89A,20
```

Comment: the [$3] in the awk command refers to the third col of the output or the input file

Comment: Fields in awk, like $3, contain the input fields